# Hide "Workspace" column on new and edit form for existing calendar event

Tags: 2007, list, calendar

How can I hide a field called 'Workspace' from Calendar: New Event or Edit Existing Event?

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the column workspace in the calendar. The place where you can also add columns.
It is described in the link:
http://mysharepointofview.com/2009/01/hide-form-fields-in-sharepoint/

Comment: you can not hide the 'Workspace' column in the regular way...

Answer (score 0):

using google ... 
http://dev-tips.blogspot.com/2010/05/hide-fields-of-sharepoint-calendar.html or
http://www.blog.anuanjan.com/?p=71
or
http://moblog.bradleyit.com/2008/10/disabling-workspaces-from-sharepoint.html

check also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969697/default-all-day-event-to-check-yes